# Penultimate stress of אתה

Tags: grammar-dikduk, trop-cantillation, vowels-nekudot

By default, the world אַתָּה *(you)* has a final stress. If I am correct (and the concordance as well), out of 172 occurrences 159 satisfies this rule in the Torah (92%).* However, if this word is in a pausal position, the stress is withdrawn to the penultimate syllable ([Bereishit 29:14](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0129.htm#14)):

> וַיֹּ֤אמֶר לוֹ֙ לָבָ֔ן אַ֛ךְ עַצְמִ֥י וּבְשָׂרִ֖י **אָ֑תָּה** וַיֵּ֥שֶׁב עִמּ֖וֹ חֹ֥דֶשׁ יָמִֽים׃
>
> And Laban said to him: "Surely **thou art** my bone and my flesh." And he abode with him the space of a month.

I have counted 7 such cases (4%). Yet, right in the next verse we see:

> וַיֹּ֤אמֶר לָבָן֙ לְיַֽעֲקֹ֔ב הֲכִֽי־אָחִ֣י **אַ֔תָּה** וַֽעֲבַדְתַּ֖נִי חִנָּ֑ם הַגִּ֥ידָה לִּ֖י מַה־מַּשְׂכֻּרְתֶּֽךָ׃
>
> And Laban said unto Jacob: 'Because **thou art** my brother, shouldest thou therefore serve me for nought? Tell me, what shall thy wages be?'

I have found 6 cases where there is a *patach* despite the penultimate stress ([Bereishit 3:19](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0103.htm#19), [22:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0122.htm#12), [29:15](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0129.htm#15), [32:17](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0132.htm#17), [49:3](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0149.htm#3), [Shemot 33:3](http://mechon-mamre.org/c/ct/c0233.htm#3)). 5 of them have *zakeif katan,* 1 has *pashta.* Aren't these disjunctives strong enough to warrant a *kamatz?* Does it happen due to a *nasog achor?* Are these cases simply exceptions?

<sup>* I have considered the words: אַתָּה, וְאַתָּה, אָתָּה, וָאָתָּה.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words אתה and עתה both have "minor" pausal forms אַ֔תָּה and עַ֔תָּה, that occur only at lesser disjunctives: tipḥa x5, zaqef qaton x23, pashta x2, and revi'a x2; and in the poetic books: etnaḥ x4 and revi'a gadol x1. The full pausal forms never appear at these disjunctives.

Why other words do not have a minor pausal form, that I can't tell you.

---

Here's a list of the minor pausal forms occurrences for אתה and עתה, respectively:

- Gen 3:19, 22:12, 29:15, 32:18, 49:3, Ex 33:3, Judg 12:5, Sam 1:17:33, 1:20:8, 1:30:13, 2:15:2, 2:15:19, Kings 1:1:42, 2:9:25, Is 41:9, 44:21, Jer 2:27, 17:17, Hos 2:25, Hab 2:16, Psa 2:7, 25:7, 40:18, 70:6, 76:8, Ezra 9:15, Chr 1:28:3, 2:14:10.
- Gen 46:34, Judg 11:7, Is 48:6, Jer 3:4, Ezek 4:14, Hag 2:3, Ruth 2:7, Dan 10:17, Chr 2:16:9.

All the counts here come from the article [Exegesis and Pausal Forms with Non-Pausal Accents in the Hebrew Bible](http://www.jamesdprice.com/images/Pausal_Forms_ETS_paper.pdf) by Dr James D. Price.

Comment: Then why I don't have a single one from 6 _zakeif gadol_ and why do I have 3 "normal" ones with _zakeif katan?_

Comment: Great question. I think we don't know much about the distribution of pausal forms, especially on lesser disjunctives. Even weirder, page 7 of the linked article lists cases where silluq and etnaḥta have non-pausal forms, for no apparent reason.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70824/bemidbar-92-why-is-the-word-pronounced-posach-with-a-kamatz/70827#comment220136_70827 magicker  did you find that on your own? @Kazi  (and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73957/sarah-is-abrahams-sister/73964#comment318321_73964)

Comment: In Torah the (triple) exception is עַ֤ם קָדוֹשׁ֙ אַתָּ֔ה לַיהוָ֖ה אֱלֹהֶ֑יךָ, where there isn't really a pause in the meaning, while in the penultimate stress case there's indeed a rhetoric pause as the article argues, so there might be something.

Comment: @DoubleAA Indeed, I have noticed it, but my question was whether it was a pausal form or a nasog achor. As a sidenote, does nasog achor work if the syllable has an additional sheva as well like this: אַ֔תָּה וְלֹ֥א?

Comment: @DoubleAA I was pointed to it by someone else (not your comment) a long time ago.